# How to center a div that is used as a submit button for a form

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` which I'm using as a submit button for my form, but I cannot figure out how to center it. When the margins are set to auto, it ends up being just slightly right off the center of the page and of other `div`s with the same css style.

```css
#submit {
 background-color: blue;
 height: 80px;
 width: 720px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form name="algForm">
  <div id='submit' onclick="document.forms['algForm'].submit();"></div>
</form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using a div that is styled to act as a form submit button - the correct html element would be either an input type="submit" or a button type="submit"- it is important to use the semantically correct element for the job and the correct element in a form is NOT the div element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think using `<div>` as a button is a good idea. Consider using `<button>` instead.

But as for your answer, what you did does work. It's just the `<div>`'s width is too big to notice.

Here's the same code with only reducing the width to 200px.

Click "Run code snippet" to see it in action.

```css
#submit {
 background-color: blue;
 height: 80px;
 width: 200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
 <form name="algForm">
   <div id='submit' onclick="document.forms['algForm'].submit();"></div>
   </form>
```

Comment: If you are using a button within a form - then you don't need the onclick event - you can simply do <button type="submit"></button> and it will automatically submit the form that it is located within.

Comment: I ended up just using a button and styling it in css instead of using a div and it is now working perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used display flex and centered items and content.  This will also keep all form elements centered.

```css
 form{
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;
 }

#submit {
 background-color: blue;
 height: 80px;
 width: 720px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
 <form name="algForm">
   <div id='submit' onclick="document.forms['algForm'].submit();"></div>
   </form>
```